# Compare two flat files A & B, to see if all records in B also exist in A

Tags: text-processing

I have two flat files A & B. A is a big file having millions of records and B is supposed to be a subset of A. A is having 20 columns with one unique key & B is having 5 columns with the same unique key. Could you please let me know how to compare B with A and find out if the records present in file B are also present in File A and have the same data in the respective columns.

Comment: If B is a subset of A, then what is the question?

Comment: it's supposed to be a subset but there could be some defects. So for the validation purpose i want to check. Actually both of the files are coming from different DB. So my task is to find out whether they are having the correct data or not.

Comment: would be better to add sample inputs and expected output (note: create one manually with few columns and few lines.. don't copy paste from your real input)

Answer (score 3):

I created two files to demonstrate my commands

`file1`:

```
1 a1 b1 c1 d1 e1
2 a2 b2 c2 d2 e2
3 a3 b3 c3 d3 e3
4 a4 b4 c4 d4 e4
5 a5 b5 c5 d5 e5
```

`file2`:

```
2 b2 c2 e2
4 b4 c4 xx
5 b5 c5 e5
```

The first column is the unique key. The common columns are column `b`, `c` and `e`. Common rows are `2`, `4` and `5`. Row `4` has a different value in column `e`.

Here is the command with output:

```
$ comm -1 -3 <(cut -d' ' -f1,3,4,6 file1) file2
4 b4 c4 xx
```

If the files are not sorted already then you can do it like this:

```
$ comm -1 -3 <(cut -d' ' -f1,3,4,6 file1 | sort) <(sort file2)
```

Explanation:

```
cut -d' ' -f1,3,4,6 file1
```

Print fields number 1, 3, 4 and 6 from file. Fields are separated by space. If the fields are separated by commas then use `cut` like this: `cut -d','`

```
<( ... )
```

[Process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst)

```
comm -1 -3 file1 file2
```

Print lines unique to file2.

Caveats:

`cut` will have problems if the separator character can occur as a character in a field.

For example:

```
"field1","field2,stillfield2","field3"
```

`cut` will not understand that the comma in `"field2,stillfield2"` is part of the field.

If your files are like that then maybe it is better to use a programming language with builtin csv handling. For example [python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Answer (score 0):

If the files have different columns as you say, the easiest way might be to write a small program using a language of your choice. `diff` and `comm` won't be much help if line structure in files is not identical.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `comm` and `diff` solution you could use `grep` for this.
Assuming your relevant data is columns 1,3, and 10 in file A and 1,2, and 3 in file B. We use `cut` to select the columns from A, use this as the keyword match file and reverse check their presence in file B. If file B has a line not present in the matching lines extracted from file A, they will be displayed. If all match, there is no output (since B supposedly is a subset of A)

```
grep -wvf <( cut -f1,3,10 fileA ) fileB
```

Or if file B has more than the three columns:

```
grep -wvf <( cut -f1,3,10 fileA ) <( cut -f1,2,3 fileB )
```